# Select test cases in a test suite

Tags: selenium, phpunit

Well i want to create a manager to be able to create a `test suite` with maybe 10 `tests cases` and be able to choose the `tests cases` to run, for example:

```
class Test extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
   constants...
   protected function setUp()
   {
        $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER);
        $this->setBrowserUrl(self::URL);
   }
   public function testFirst()
   {
        code...
   }
   public function testSecond()
   {
        code...
   }
   public function testThird()
   {
        code...
   }
}
```

I want to be able to tell to `phpunit` to just run testFirst and testSecond and will not execute testThird.

I have a idea to do this:
 Creating separated `testSuites` (classes) one for each test.

There is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not related to this question, but tests should be runned absolute independent of each other. Read more about [F.I.R.S.T](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024785/tdd-first-principle)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my tests are independent but for example i have a class with a lot of tests then the time to executed all tests is too long... That's why i want to be able to choose my own tests without running everything.  I will read the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests should be runned independent and fast.

Not always all tests executed fast, so i usally run tests for custom directory or suite when i delevop some module, and run all tests when i want check that my work don't break other parts of system. **It's a bad practice!** Better do a fast tests, and move slow tests in extra suite if you can't change them.

I recomend read more about good testing principles that called [F.I.R.S.T](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.de/2009/02/first.html)

> **Fast**: run (subset of) tests quickly (since you'll be running them all the time)
>
> **Independent**: no tests depend on others, so can run any subset in any order
>
> **Repeatable**: run N times, get same result (to help isolate bugs and enable automation)
>
> **Self-checking**: test can automatically detect if passed (no human checking of output)
>
> **Timely**: written about the same time as code under test (with TDD, written first!)